Unable to start a any task in Google cloud composer using DataflowCreatePythonJobOperator
import airflow
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.dataflow import DataflowCreatePythonJobOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

default_args = {
    'start_date': airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(0),
    'retries': 0,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=1)
}

dag = DAG(
    'custom_python_operator',
    default_args=default_args,
    description='Just runs templates',
    schedule_interval='0 * * * *',
    max_active_runs=1,
    catchup=False,
    dagrun_timeout=timedelta(minutes=10),
)

dataflow_job = DataflowCreatePythonJobOperator(
    task_id='run_dataflow_pipeline',
    py_file='./template_runner_scripts/MultiSoapAPI_repeat_bkp.py',  # GCS path
    job_name='direct-script-1617' ,
    project_id='ai-data-ingestion-staging',
    location='us-central1',
    options={
        'ip_configuration': 'WORKER_IP_PUBLIC'
    },
    py_requirements=['apache-beam[gcp]==2.21.0'],
    py_interpreter='python3',
    py_system_site_packages=False
)

dataflow_job

No tasks are getting generated in composer ui
As you can see in the above code we can see that no tasks are getting generated and code directory and everythings seems alright and I can't see any error.

The task isn't assigned to a DAG. You can either explicitly set the dag arg to each one of your tasks like so:

dag = DAG(
    'custom_python_operator',
    ...,
)

dataflow_job = DataflowCreatePythonJobOperator(
    task_id='run_dataflow_pipeline',
    ...
    dag=dag,
)

Or, use the DAG object as a context manager. In this approach you don't need to explicitly set the dag arg for every task.
with DAG(
    'custom_python_operator',
    ...,
):
    dataflow_job = DataflowCreatePythonJobOperator(
    task_id='run_dataflow_pipeline',
    ...,
    )

